# custom control textbox and implicit style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, textblock

We are trying to make an impliced style for a custom textblock control that we made.
This custom control is base on a text block and adds a few DP and Logic.
When we use the style locally everything works fine. Also when we give the style a key it also works.

**This is the custom control inheritince code:**

```
public class HighlightTextBlock : TextBlock
```

**and this is the style:**

```
    <Style TargetType="UI:HighlightTextBlock"
       x:Name="LocalHighlightTextBlockStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleHighlightTextBlockDefault}">
  <Setter Property="HighlightedText"
          Value="{Binding ElementName=txtSearchBox, Path=Text}"></Setter> 
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Tomato"></Setter>
  <!--<Setter Property="HighlightedText" Value="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
              Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
              AncestorType={x:Type UI:GenericWatchControl}}, Path=SearchTextBoxContent}" />-->
  <!--<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static ProfilingServerShared:MissingDataValue.NotAvailableText}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>-->
</Style>
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override metadata in `HighlightTextBlock` static constructor, as such:

```
public partial class HighlightTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    static HighlightTextBlock()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HighlightTextBlock), 
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HighlightTextBlock)));
    }
}
```

If you do not do this, by default, the `HighlightTextBlock` will try to find implicit style for `TextBlock`, not `HighglightTextBlock`.

Comment: Hi Chris I did so but it doesn't help.

Comment: @iag_oz: you should use Snoop (google), and see whatr exactly is happening in the visual tree. You can also inspect the 'Style' attribute.

Comment: your answer is partially correct, I have to mention that we should add an implicit style to a theme or generic XAML files, and then it will work well. Thanks I'll mark your answer as a correct.